# C++ error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to call a void function named `correction(original,corrected)` and when I'm trying to compile it I get a couple of errors of the form:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token

Here is my complete code:

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    void correction(ifstream& original,ofstream& corrected);

    int main ()
    {
      ifstream original;
      ofstream corrected;
      char filename[16];
      cout<<"Enter filename:\n";
      cin>>filename;
      original.open(filename);
      corrected.open("corrected.txt");
      if (original.fail( ))
        {
    cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
          exit(1);
        }
    if (corrected.fail( ))
      {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
      }
     else
       {
         correction(original,corrected);
}
 return 0;
}

void correction(ifstream& original,ofstream& corrected)
{
char symbol;
while(! original.eof())
  {
    original.get(symbol);
    if (symbol== 'c')
{
     corrected.put(symbol);
     original.get(symbol);
     if (symbol=='i')
       {
         corrected.put(symbol);
         original.get(symbol);
         if (symbol=='n')
           {
             corrected.put(symbol);
             original.get(symbol);
while (symbol==' ')
                 {
                   original.get(symbol);
                     }
             for (symbol=='<')
               {
                 corrected.put('>');
                 original.get(symbol);
               }
             corrected.put(symbol);
           }
}
     if (symbol=='o')
       {
         corrected.put(symbol);
         original.get(symbol);
         if (symbol=='u')
           {
             corrected.put(symbol);
             original.get(symbol);
             if (symbol=='t')
               {
                 corrected.put(symbol);
                original.get(symbol);
                 while (symbol==' ')
                   {
                     original.get(symbol);
                   }
                 for (symbol=='>')
                   {
                     corrected.put('<');
                     original.get(symbol);
                   }
                 corrected.put(symbol);
               }
           }
       }
   }
 else
   corrected.put(symbol);
  }
 return;
}
```

When I try to compile this code I get the following errors:

> > operators.cpp:59:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
> >            for (symbol=='<')
> >                            ^ operators.cpp:65:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
> >          }
> >          ^ operators.cpp:65:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token > >operators.cpp:65:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’
> >     token 
> >     operators.cpp:65:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
> >     operators.cpp:83:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
> >         for (symbol=='>')
> >                         ^ operators.cpp:89:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
> >              }
> >              ^ operators.cpp:89:9: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token operators.cpp:89:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’
> >     token operators.cpp:89:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token

I am kind of new to programming and have spent a couple of hours trying to fix it but I don't understand what the problem is.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `for (symbol=='<')` ?? Did you mean `if (symbol=='<')`? The error specifies line 59 and also shows the problem.

Comment: The errors clearly show the location of the error and what's wrong. Get a good editor or IDE and they will also show you the syntax errors.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, at the risk of being misunderstood, I will partially disagree. There is a reason why they ask to write code on paper or boards in the interviews. I'm inclined to believe that one should develop his/herself towards being able to write correct code on their own, including the use of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

**Added later after looking closely at @liup's answer:**

Ouch, my bad, the OP probably indeed meant to use a loop here! Then, you can use the while loop like so:

```
while (symbol=='<')
```

and

```
while (symbol=='>')
```

**Old answer:**

Here:

```
if (symbol=='<')
```

and here:

```
if (symbol=='>')
```

Instead of `for (symbol=='<')` and `for (symbol=='>')`.

The error stems from the fact that in a `for` loop, you must have all the three clauses, even if they are empty, hence two semicolons `;` are obligatory. You <del>only provided one</del> didn't provide a single semicolon in each of the two incorrect `for` statements.

For reference, see [for loop description at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

Answer (score 1):

Both `for (symbol=='<')` and `for (symbol=='>')` for loop syntax is wrong. In this scenario you can use for loop as follows.

```
for (; symbol == '<';)
{
    corrected.put('>');
    original.get(symbol);
} 

for (; symbol == '>';)
{
    corrected.put('<');
    original.get(symbol);
}
```

OR

```
for (; symbol == '<';original.get(symbol))
{
    corrected.put('>');

} 

for (; symbol == '>';original.get(symbol))
{
    corrected.put('<');

}
```